# Firebug showing reponse too quickly because page is redirecting

Tags: ajax, debugging, firebug

I'm new with Firebug and I'm trying to debug some Ajax. When I click the submit button on a form there is an Ajax response from the server which appears in the Firebug console but it disappears in a split second. In the HTML source code I set the `action=""` but the page still reloads and the response in Firebugs console is still lost. How can I use Firebug to view the response even after the page has redirected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways:

- Check the Network tab in Firebug. The request and response might still be in there.
- In the Scripts tab, try to find the code that is doing the redirection and set a breakpoint. Hit the "Stop at next breakpoint" button. Then execution will halt before the redirection code.

Comment: The first didn't work because it didn't show the PHP script that processed the AJAX request, instead it showed the PHP script that processed the form data after the page had been submitted. Your second idea work and I learned something new :-)